# Currently without a lease, the lease my landlord sent me has 2 distinct errors

Tags: rental-property, residential-lease, rent, breaking-the-lease

Can I cross things out and fix those 2 errors, and send him a signed lease with my edits, or should I wait for him to fix the errors himself.  I told my landlord about the 2 errors and we're currently on a month to month situation.   He wants the lease signed.  I don't want to sign a lease that has errors in it.

For the specifics.  One line says "no cats", my last lease allowed for cats, but this one doesn't.  My landlord knows I have cats.  This paragraph should be removed in my opinion.

The larger issue.   I'm moving soon, and the landlord knows this.  I need to move for family reasons.   The landlord said that's OK if I give him 2 months notice.  Month to month rent is usually 30 days, but I understand that this is inconvenient for him as well, so I don't mind terribly giving him 60 days, though I suspect he'll screw me on the deposit as well, so it's more like 90, but the lease is written in such a way that it could be interpreted that I'm promising the full 12 months.  It says both that I can terminate with 60 days notice and that I promise to pay for the full 12 months.  I asked him to fix that.  He got mad at me and told me "it's all boilerplate", but that didn't exactly put me at ease.

My question is, should I wait for his updates or can I make these edits myself and send him a signed lease with two paragraphs crossed out and/or heavily edited.     I'm inclined to think that if I don't sign, it's to my advantage, but I'm not sure what my rights are without a signed lease.

My landlord has a bad reputation and he's an LLC, more than an actual human and somebody told me that he's not even a legal landlord, but I'm not sure what that means.  None of the renters like him at all.    But that's just backstory.   The main question is, can I cross out 2 paragraphs in the lease he sent me and sign it?   Is that legal, or is it the landlords responsibility to give me a proper lease with the verbal agreement of 60 days notice, before I sign anything?

I want to add that when I told him I needed to move, he was actually nice on the phone for a change and he suggested 60 days notice, but it was verbal, not written.   80% of the time, he's rude and he drops threats or accusations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify and sign the lease document, but that won't create a lease agreement. The landlord would need to also agree to the modifications. They could do something like signing the modified document.

Only your lawyer can really work out if you would be better off proposing a modification to your landlord's proposed agreement, or just doing nothing.

In many jurisdictions, without a lease agreement, you are a month to month tenant and can be made to leave with one month's notice for no particular reason. With a lease agreement for a year, if you leave, the landlord usually has to expeditiously re-rent to someone else, but you can often be required to pay the rent payments until that someone else is actually found, or your lease term ends.

It's worth checking what the rules are in your jurisdiction specifically. They vary and they often override whatever the contract says.